# Open arbitary file from Finder in TextMate

Tags: finder, textmate, file-extensions

In Finder, I see a file with the ".rel" extension.  I'd like top open it in TextMate.  I don't see TextMate in the list of choices, and, in fact, can't find it anywhere in the list of applications when I try to choose the application to open it with.

How can I tell Finder to open the file in TextMate, either now or always (by default)? How can I open an arbitrary file (i.e. even one with a known extension) from Finder in TextMate?

TextMate v2.0-beta.6
OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: If You have TextMate in Dock -> You can drag the file to TextMate icon.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the file in Finder.
2. Press **⌘I** to Get Info.
3. Set **None** to **Other…** in the Open With section of the inspector:

   [image]
4. Enable **All Applications**, then find and choose TextMate.
5. Select **Change All…** to change the association for all .rel files.

Answer (score 0):

To open any kind of file with TextMate (or other Applications)

*…just once:*
**drag&drop** it on the application icon (in the Dock or in the Finder)

*…by default:*
change the default application by using either:
- the **file info** dialogue in the Finder (see grgarside's answer)
- or with the freeware **[RCDefault](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)** - my favorite! With this preference pane you can manage all kinds of default associations to applications on your Mac.